# GDB backtrace without stopping

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb, signals

I am trying to let my program run continously with GDB.
Currently I have a bash script which starts GDB with my program and when it crashes it prints the backtrace and starts GDB again (endless loop).

Now I added a signal handler for my program which kills specific threads when the handler gets a signal from them. Now I can achieve that GDB does not stop by doing this:

```
handle SIGSEGV nostop
```

But this leads me to the problem that I do not get a GDB backtrace which I would like to print automatically without stopping the program (or at least continuing automatically).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Since you're already able to handle your own SIGSEGV (thus subverting GDB), doesn't it make sense to put the backtrace dump in your SIGSEGV hander rather than relying on an external tool?

Comment: I am already printing backtraces in my handler, but they are not as detailed as those of GDB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continue to use `handle` to suppress ordinary stops from `SEGV`.  Then set a catchpoint that does what you want:

```
(gdb) catch signal SIGSEGV
(gdb) commands
    >   silent  # this bit is optional
    >   bt
    >   continue
    >   end
```

This will print a backtrace on `SIGSEGV` but not otherwise interfere with normal operation.  You may also want `handle SIGSEGV noprint`.